# Passing string array from python to C and using in for loop (code included)

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am trying to pass in two string arrays from python into C, using them in a nested for loop, comparing them against a parameter, and if the two strings meet this parameter, I append them into a new string array in C. The function ends with me returning the new array of compared strings. This function is called in python using CDLL, and this new string array is used is my python script.

```
#In Python:

PyOne = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]
PyTwo = ["Cucumber", "Mango", "Pineapple", "Apple"]
```

I have translated these for use in my C function as follows:

```
#In Python:

PyOne = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]
PyOne_bytes = []
for i in range(len(PyOne)):
    PyOne_bytes.append(bytes(PyOne[i], 'utf-8'))
One_array = (ctypes.c_char_p * (len(PyOne_bytes)+1))()
One_array[:-1] = PyOne_bytes

PyTwo = ["Cucumber", "Mango", "Pineapple", "Apple"]
PyTwo_bytes = []
for i in range(len(PyTwo)):
    PyTwo_bytes(bytes(PyTwo[i], 'utf-8'))
Two_array = (ctypes.c_char_p * (len(PyTwo_bytes)+1))()
Two_array[:-1] = PyTwo_bytes
```

The above code translates the existing Python string array into one that is interpretable by C.

This is my C function:

```
// In C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SCALING_FACTOR 0.1
#include <ctype.h>

...

char ** mainForLoop(const char ** PyOne, const char ** PyTwo) {
    char ** matches = malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(PyOne)/sizeof(PyOne[0]); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < sizeof(PyTwo)/sizeof(PyTwo[0]); j++) {
            double v = comparison(PyOne[i], PyTwo[i]);
            if (v > 4) {
                strcat(matches, (PyOne[i]));
                strcat(matches, (";"));
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

In python, I then print the returned value from the function as follows:

```
c.mainForLoop.argtypes = [POINTER(c_char_p), POINTER(c_char_p)]
c.mainForLoop.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

print(c.mainForLoop(One_array, Two_array))
```

If, for example, comparison("Apple", "Cucumber") = 5 (i.e. > 4), comparison("Orange", "Mango") = 7 (i.e. > 4), and everything other comparison() < 4, then I would expect, due to the following...

```
// In C
double v = comparison(PyOne[i], PyTwo[i]);
                if (v > 4) {
                    strcat(matches, (PyOne[i]));
                    strcat(matches, (";"));
                }
```

for

```
#In Python
print(cDoc.mainForLoop(One_array, Two_array))

>>> b'Apple;Orange'
```

but currently, this prints:

```
>>> b'Apple;'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in my code. I'm somewhat new to C, and I've tried everything I can think of, any help would be appreciated, an explanation would also be ace!

Thank you!

**EDIT:
Following on the from the answers below, this is my new code:**

```
// In C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


void free_list(char** list, size_t size) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) if (list[i]) free(list[i]);
    free(list);
}

char ** mainForLoop(const char ** PyOne, const char ** PyTwo, size_t sizeOne, size_t sizeTwo) {
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    char ** matches = malloc(sizeOne * sizeof(char *));

    char temp[100] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < sizeOne; i++) {
        // Cleared on each pass
        temp[0] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < sizeTwo; j++) {
            double v = similarity(PyOne[i], PyTwo[j]);
            if (v > 4) {
                // Works with the temp buffer
                strcat(temp, (PyOne[i]));
                strcat(temp, (";"));
                int size = strlen(temp) + 1; //+1 for null termination

                char * str = malloc(size);
                memcpy(str, temp, size);
                str[size-1] = 0; //Null termination

                matches[i] = str;
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
    free_list(matches, sizeOne);
}



#In Python
dll = CDLL("c.file")
dll.mainForLoop.argtypes = POINTER(c_char_p),POINTER(c_char_p),c_size_t,c_size_t
dll.mainForLoop.restype = POINTER(c_char_p)
dll.free_list.argtypes = POINTER(c_char_p),c_size_t
dll.free_list.restype = None

def make_clist(lst):
    return (c_char_p * len(lst))(*[x.encode() for x in lst])

def mainForLoop(list1,list2):
    size = c_size_t()
    result = dll.mainForLoop(make_clist(list1),make_clist(list2),len(list1),len(list2))
    data = [x.decode() for x in result[:size.value]]
    dll.free_list(result,size.value)
    return data

list1 = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]
list2 = ["Apple", "Mango", "Pineapple", "Apple"]
print(mainForLoop(list1,list2))
```

However, this returns:

> []

Please note that the "comparison()" function in C is a string distance calculation that returns a double value by comparing two strings.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: The C code is incorrect.  `sizeof(PyOne)` for example, is the size of the `char**` type (4 or 8 depending on 32- or 64-bit OS).  The math being used should only be used on arrays.  In this case, the answer to `sizeof(PyOne)/sizeof(PyOne[0])` will always be 1.

Comment: You've also allocated memory for 100 `char*`, but those pointers are uninitialized, so a `strcat` to one of those pointers is "bad".

Comment: @MarkTolonen I did this but it still hasn't fixed the issue. I think the for loop cuts if v < 4, and does not go on to check any of the other items. OR it only matches PyOne[0] with PyTwo[0], or PyOne[3] with PyTwo[3], but not any that are in different positions. Still stuck unfortunately

Comment: In the new code, `free_list` after `return` does nothing, and it shouldn't be called in the C code at all.  `matches[i] = str` overwrites malloced pointers if more than one PyTwo items match PyOne.  Instead just `matches[i] = _strdup(temp)` outside the `j` loop once the string is built and remove all the sizing/malloc.  In the Python code, I *think* you want to use `size = len(list1)`  and use `size` instead of `size.value` in the two locations used.  Also hope the resulting strings never exceed tmp[100].  Buffer overflow risk there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C code provided is incorrect, so here is demo showing how to pass and return byte arrays.  This example just appends the two lists together.  It also handles freeing the memory so there is no memory leak from the memory allocations in C.

test.c:

```c
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

API char** append_lists(const char** list1, size_t size1, const char** list2, size_t size2, size_t* pSize) {
    char** total = malloc((size1 + size2) * sizeof(char*));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size1; ++i)
        total[i] = _strdup(list1[i]);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size2; ++i)
        total[size1 + i] = _strdup(list2[i]);
    *pSize = size1 + size2;
    return total;
}

API void free_list(char** list, size_t size) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        free(list[i]);
    free(list);
}
```

test.py:

```py
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.append_lists.argtypes = POINTER(c_char_p),c_size_t,POINTER(c_char_p),c_size_t,POINTER(c_size_t)
dll.append_lists.restype = POINTER(c_char_p)
dll.free_list.argtypes = POINTER(c_char_p),c_size_t
dll.free_list.restype = None

# Helper function to turn Python list of Unicode strings
# into a ctypes array of byte strings.
def make_clist(lst):
    return (c_char_p * len(lst))(*[x.encode() for x in lst])

# Helper function to convert the lists, make the call correctly,
# convert the return result back into a Python list of Unicode strings,
# and free the C allocations.
def append_lists(list1,list2):
    size = c_size_t()
    result = dll.append_lists(make_clist(list1),len(list1),make_clist(list2),len(list2),byref(size))
    data = [x.decode() for x in result[:size.value]]
    dll.free_list(result,size.value)
    return data

list1 = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]
list2 = ["Cucumber", "Mango", "Pineapple", "Apple"]
print(append_lists(list1,list2))
```

Output:

```py
['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Cucumber', 'Mango', 'Pineapple', 'Apple']
```

Comment: Amazing, this should solve it, I'll have to have a look in a couple hours and if all is well I'll put this as the right answer. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've tested your code and it works, but it doesn't solve the problem regarding a nested for loop to compare to string items. I tried to implement dspr's code into this but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @HarrisAhmed I don’t know what you want to do with your comparison.  My answer shows how to pass the strings back and forth and use them in a loop.

Comment: It is a string comparison algorithm I have created, so it takes in the two strings, uses a string distance calculation and returns the double value. This function works correctly. This is why it requires a nested for loop. I have tried to implement this but it's not returning any values/crashes. Any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: The array sizes are given to the C function already. In the python function "mainForLoop", the array sizes are calculated from Len(list1) and Len(list2), and passed into C as follows: "result = dll.mainForLoop(make_clist(list1),make_clist(list2),len(list1),len(list2))". I still receive the same problem.

Comment: @HarrisAhmed You've dropped returning the number of valid strings in `matches`.  `size = c_size_t()` is left at its default value...zero.  Also, debugging your C code is really another question.  How many strings can be returned?  What's the algorithm?  It looks like 0-sizeOne matches can be returned, but the number needs to be known to process the returned strings correctly.  The main question is answered.  An upvote/accept would be appreciated.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you for your help, I will leave the question open for a couple more days and if there is no better answer I will accept yours, as I am still stuck. I've debugged the edited the code and it is clean, it would be no problem to show the algorithm but it's not necessary, all that needs to be known is that it returns a double value. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the number of valid strings in matches has been dropped?

Comment: @HarrisAhmed My example has a `size_t* pSize` parameter that indicates the number of strings allocated in the return value.  I think you assume the number of strings returned is `sizeOne` but unsure.  You need to fix the size value used in the Python code to use `len(list1)` if that is your intent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example closer than your configuration. Note that my `main`function is just there to run the example, in you case it would be useless.

The main fix is that I allocate memory for each new string what you didn't do (you allocated the memory for pointers but not for the strings themselves). To do that I first use a 100 characters temporary buffer on the stack (you can make it longer if needed) and, once the length of the string is known, I allocate it (note that the function you prepared for freeing these strings  and pointers (free_list) is already correct) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

double comparison(const char * one, const char * two) {
    int try = rand() % 12;
    return try;
}

char ** mainForLoop(char ** PyOne, char ** PyTwo, int sizeOne, int sizeTwo) {
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;
    
    // Allocate an array of N string pointers where N is the size of PyOne
    char ** matches = malloc(sizeOne * sizeof(char *));
    // The temporary buffer
    char temp[100] = {0};
    
    for (i = 0; i < sizeOne; i++) {
        // Cleared on each pass
        temp[0] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < sizeTwo; j++) {
            double v = comparison(PyOne[i], PyTwo[j]);
            if (v > 4) {
                // Works with the temp buffer
                strcat(temp, (PyOne[i]));
                strcat(temp, (";"));
                int size = strlen(temp) + 1; //+1 for null termination

                // Then allocates a string of the right size
                char * str = malloc(size);
                memcpy(str, temp, size);
                str[size-1] = 0; //Null termination

                // And collects it
                matches[i] = str;
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
}


void free_list(char** list, size_t size) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) if (list[i]) free(list[i]);
    free(list);
}


int main() {
    // Initializes random
    srand(time(0));
    int N = 3;
    char * PyOne[3] = {"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};
    char * PyTwo[4] = {"Cucumber", "Mango", "Pineapple", "Apple"};
    
    char ** matches = mainForLoop(PyOne, PyTwo, N, 4);

    // Prints the result which is possibly (depending on random) :
    // "Apple; Orange; Banana;Banana;"

    for (char i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%s ", matches[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // Frees
    free_list(matches, N);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This probably works, but the main reason for the use of C is for my python arrays to be processed quickly, so I still need to know how to import arrays into C and to also return an array to python properly processed.

Comment: I edited my post to give a example closer to you needs

Comment: Hi @dspr , thank you, would you be able to show how to implement this on the python side, as I can't seem to export the function to work with my python string arrays. If you could, I'd give top answer as it solves the problem! thanks!

Comment: Normally something like this should be sufficient : `print(cDoc.mainForLoop(One_array, Two_array, len(PyOne), len(PyTwo))))`. But before trying that, you have to : 1) finalize the `comparison` function (I don't have the info required to do it myself) 2) move `free_list(matches, sizeOne)` at the end of the `mainForLoop` function (since you don't have a C `main` as in my example) 3) choose the best maximum size for you matches (I used 100 but you could need more).

Comment: the comparison function is a string distance calculation that takes in 2 strings and returns a double value. What do you mean by finalise? I have put free_list(matches, sizeOne) below, but the python script just returns an empty array

Comment: In my example, I did replace this test by a random one because I didn't know what to do. I meant that this part has to be replaced with the real test.

Comment: I have taken into account everything you have said and put the edited and updated code above, this still only returns an empty "[]" in python, if you could have a look and suggest anything it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Harris Ahmed (sorry I did post that at the wrong place...) 1) print(mainForLoop(list1,list2)) lacks the array sizes. 2) free_list is placed after return so it is never executed. However I was wrong about that : you cannot free the array before it has been converted to an array of python strings. So you really  have to use another function doing that from python after the end of the procedure. I'm afraid I cannot help you more than that because I don't know anything about python/C bridge, my first attempt was to help you with pure c code. Good luck !